# Listen/output bytes from port 80 on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I am teaching myself some Linux network programming, just getting a feel for how it works. I found [this tutorial](http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c).

which will print out the first X bytes returned from the google server. I have tried this example and it works. However, I was wondering how would I modify the code so that I could just output whatever bytes came through on a particular port number?

I am working with C/C++ on Linux Mint.

Comment: Just loop around `recv()` until `0`is returned  (connection closed by peer) or an error occurred (`-1` is returned).

Comment: As the example code is C++ are you sure you tagged this question correctly?

Comment: @alk I tagged C because the OS functions are C (or so I thought?)

Comment: @alk but why do they specify the google web address specifically if I want to listen for any traffic on port 80?

Comment: The code does not listen on port 80, it does connect to port 80 on google.com sends a http-request and `recv()`s what the server connected to sends back as response.

Comment: But it says: "Therefore we need to provide our socket with the address (google.com), the address type (ipv4), the port (webservers usually run on port 80)" so it does need THE address? Whereas I just want to listen to any data entering a port?

Comment: Another tutorial here where you must provide the "server address": http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html

Comment: I didn't say no address is needed. The program needs an address to connect to: google.com:80 using IPv4. That's all.

Comment: Ok so my question is, what if I want to output all packets which arrive via port 80, from multiple/unknown addresses? A bit like wireshark network packet sniffing

Comment: If you do not run a program listening on port 80 on your machine, nothing "*arrives via port 80*". However you might like to take a look at *libpcap*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap#libpcap But probably you'd better start from the bottom, perhaps looking into this: http://www.unpbook.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the link that you are reading, the code has been written to read the first 1000 bytes of information and stop with that.

`bytes_received = recv(socketfd, incoming_data_buffer,1000, 0);`

If you want to read all the bytes returned from your request you would need to use a while loop like the one below:

```
while(bytes_received = recv(socketfd, incoming_data_buffer,1000, 0)>=0){
    if (bytes_received == 0) 
        break;
    std::cout<<incoming_data_buffer<<endl; //Output the data
    std::cout<<bytes_received<<endl; //Output the number of bytes recieved
}
```